# Lodash/Underscore : Check for a value within an array, in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Confusing title, the only simple way to explain is to show you what I'm after :

```
var user = [
  {foo:"test",bar:1},
  {foo:"test2",bar:2}
];

var items = [{foo:"test",bar:1},{foo:"test4",bar:4},{foo:"test5",bar:5}]
```

What I want, is to pick **one item** from `items` which is not already in `user`, and add it to `user`. In this case the `user` object would end up looking like :

```
user = [
  {foo:"test",bar:1},
  {foo:"test2",bar:2},
  {foo:"test4",bar:4}
];
```

I've tried all sorts of _.filter, _.contains, etc... combinations, but can't quite figure it out. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why `test4` but not `test5`?

Comment: cus that would be selfish if one user would take all the items ;) could be one or the other though, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is as follows: you want to find the first item that is not contained within the `user` array.

So you can do the following:

```
var item = _.find(items, function (item) {
    return !_.findWhere(user, item);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xqL86q3p/1/)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty, I was already starting to write an ugly for loop to do the job. Thanks!